# Como preencher a matriz por linha? em R

Tags: r

Por que no código abaixo mesmo com o argumento `byrow=TRUE` a matriz está sendo preenchida por coluna?

```
matriz <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE) 

for (i in 1:50) { 

  aqui <- sample(1:6, size=1) 
  print(aqui) 
  matriz[i]<- aqui 
  print(matriz)

}
```

Comment: Postei uma resposta, mas vou reforçar o conselho dado em outra pergunta similar sua: estude mais profundamente indexação. É um dos recursos mais básicos e poderosos da linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

Porque essa é a ordem de indexação de um arranjo, independente de como foi criado. Para indexar uma linha, deve fornecer o índice com a coordenada adequada. Compare:

```
a2 <- array(1:12, c(2,6))

a2[2]

a2[2, ]

a2[, 2]
```

Matriz é um caso especial de arranjo com 2 dimensões:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, 2, 6)

identical(a2, m)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Por ser um caso comum, a função `matrix` possui a opção de distribuir os valores por linha. Mas ela não altera a maneira com que será indexada, apenas reordena os elementos no vetor ao criar o arranjo:

```
mr <- matrix(1:12, 2, 6, byrow = TRUE)

str(m)
#>  int [1:2, 1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

m[2]
#> [1] 2

str(mr)
#>  int [1:2, 1:6] 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 11 ...

mr[2]
#> [1] 7
```

Para linhas, deve usar a primeira coordenada, não importa como a matriz foi gerada. Por exemplo:

```
matriz <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 5)

for (i in 1:nrow(matriz)) {
  a <- sample(1:6, size = ncol(matriz))
  print(a)
  matriz[i,] <- a
  print(matriz)
}
```